# How to display objects related through ManyToMany via prefetch_related?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, view, django-orm

**UPDATE**
I was able to accomplish this in my Project models.py, but I feel this belongs in my view. How would I go about doing this? Code:

```
@property
def related_project_set(self):
    category_id_list = self.category.values_list("id", flat=True)
    return Project.live.filter(category__id__in=category_id_list).exclude(id=self.id)[:5]
```

---

I'd like to display "projects" related by "category" in my generic class-based detail view for project. I'm also using the Django-Braces PrefetchRelated Mixin. But I don't understand why the Python interpreter displays different results than my template.

For example, given two projects in the db, I get the following result:

```
>>> from projects.models import Project
>>> Project.objects.all().prefetch_related('category')
[<Project: Avalon Road>, <Project: Piedmont Avenue>]
```

Models:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    """
    A project completed by ICON.

    """
    LIVE_STATUS = 1
    DRAFT_STATUS = 2
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (LIVE_STATUS, 'Live'),
        (DRAFT_STATUS, 'Draft'),
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text='Populates from title field.')
    date_completed = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    vison_description = models.TextField(help_text='Please use Markdown syntax. No HTML is allowed.')
    work_description = models.TextField(help_text='Please use Markdown syntax. No HTML is allowed.')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category)
    lead_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='projects/photos', help_text='Will also be used as thumbnail for category listing.')
    gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=2, help_text="Only projects with a status of 'live' will be displayed publicly.")

    objects = models.Manager()
    live = LiveProjectManager()

class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.SlugField(help_text='Populates from title field.')
    description = models.TextField(help_text='Please use Markdown syntax. No HTML is allowed.', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
        ordering = ('title',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.slug

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('categories:detail',
                (), 
                {'slug': self.slug})
```

Views:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from braces.views import PrefetchRelatedMixin

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

from .models import Project
from categories.models import Category
from testimonials.models import Testimonial

class ProjectDetailView(PrefetchRelatedMixin, DetailView):
    prefetch_related = ['category']
    queryset = Project.live.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Allow the project detail view to display a list of testimonials.

        """
        context = super(ProjectDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['testimonial_list'] = Testimonial.displayed.all()
        return context

class ProjectListView(ListView):
    queryset = Project.live.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Allow the project list view to display a list of categories.

        """
        context = super(ProjectListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category_list'] = Category.objects.all()
        return context
```

Template snippet:

```
<ul>
{% for project in object.category.all %}
    <li>{{ project.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: You mentioned the template output is different from the shell but didn't show the template results.

Comment: Apologies. Here is the template output:`<ul><li>Kitchens</li></ul>`. Basically this is the category for the Project, but not the projects related via the category.